# How to turn the image in the correct orientation?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a paper on which there are scans of documents, I use tesseract to recognize the text, but sometimes the images are in the wrong orientation, then I cut these documents from the sheet and work with each one individually, but I need to turn them in the correct position, how to do it?

Comment: If all the documents are "credit card shape", you can detect rectangles in your image, and thus rotate the image such that the long end for example is horizontal.

Comment: It might be better to blur your id image here however, now you are exposing yourself to "identity fraud".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Will it work on a vertical plane?

Comment: If the scans include EXIF data, then there is a field that identifies the orientation as a number between 1 and 8. See https://sirv.com/help/resources/rotate-photos-to-be-upright/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if there are simple ways, but you can rotate the document after you do not find adequate characters in it, if you see letters, then the document is in the correct orientation.

As I understand it, you use a parser, so the check can be very simple, if there are less than 5 keys, then the document is turned upside down incorrectly

Comment: Good idea. I will try.

Comment: @question_mark_77 I hope everything works out for you

Answer (score 1):

If all scans are in same orientation on the paper, then you can always try rotating it in reverse if tesseract is causing the problem in reading. If individual scans can be in arbitrary orientation, then you will have to use the same method on individual scans instead.